# How to decode session value from Redis cache?

Tags: django, session, redis

For authentication, I decided to use sessions stored in the Redis cache.

In setting.py, I added:

```
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.redis.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0",
    }
}

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
```

There was a need to read all the sessions that are available. To do this, I run the following code

```
r = redis.StrictRedis('localhost', 6379, db=0, decode_responses=True)
 
for key in r.keys():
    print('Key:', key)
    print('Value:', r.get(key))
```

If decode_responses=False, everything works, but the response looks like this

```
Key: b':1:django.contrib.sessions.cachec2ynyeuinke4i4815oi7bjjf3jzx100s'
Value: b'\x80\x05\x95%\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94(\x8c\x0f_session_expiry\x94K<\x8c\x07user_id\x94K\x01u.'
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
> return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
> response = self.handle_exception(exc)
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
> self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
> raise exc
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
> response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\accounts\views.py", line 65, in post
> print('Value:', r.get(key))
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\redis\commands\core.py", line 1829, in get
> return self.execute_command("GET", name)
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 536, in execute_command
> return conn.retry.call_with_retry(
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\redis\retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
> return do()
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 537, in 
> lambda: self._send_command_parse_response(
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 513, in _send_command_parse_response
> return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 553, in parse_response
> response = connection.read_response()
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 500, in read_response
> response = self._parser.read_response(disable_decoding=disable_decoding)
> File "C:\Users\adrian\PyCharmProjects\TestProject\venv\lib\site-packages\redis_parsers\hiredis.py", line 128, in read_response
> response = self._reader.gets()
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
> [28/Nov/2023 20:57:21] "POST /api/accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 129875

**SOLUTION**

```
 r = redis.StrictRedis('localhost', 6379, db=0, decode_responses=False)

for key in r.keys():
    print('Key:', key)
    print(pickle.loads(r.get(key)))
```

Comment: You need to deserialize it. 
Django typically uses the pickle module for serialization.

Comment: @NonameNoSurname, thanks!